# Writing a potential energy matrix in two dimensions with python

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, simulations, software

I am using the finite difference method to solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation. To use the method we need to make everything discrete so the potential $V(x)$ becomes a $N\times N$ matrix $\textrm{diag}[V(x_0),\cdots,V(x_N)]$.
In one dimension, one can write

```
x = np.linspace(-L/2,L/2,N) 
def Vpot(x):
   return x**2
V = np.zeros((N))
for i in range(N):
    V[i]= Vpot(x[i])
```

I like this way because we can easily change the form of `Vpot`, put some IF and so on. For instance, suppose that I want to write a potential well in 1D, I can change `Vpot`

```
def Vpot(x):
    V0=100
    dl=0.25
    if -dl/2 < x < dl/2:
        return -V0
    else:
        return 0.0
```

For two dimensions, I am calculating the potential matrix like that:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-L/2,L/2,N), np.linspace(-L/2,L/2,N))
U = x**2 + y**2
V = sparse.diags(U.reshape(N**2),(0))
```

It only works when we have a continuous function $U$ that describe the potential.

I want write a function `Vpot(x,y)` that can be written as a diagonal matrix $V$ (like in 1D). How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

In order to clarify my problem, I will show what happens if I use the very same logic but two-dimensional.

After using

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-L/2,L/2,N), np.linspace(-L/2,L/2,N))
```

both x and y become matrices $N\times N$ and if I use, for example

```
def Vpot(x,y):
    V0=100
    dl=0.25
    if -dl/2 < x < dl/2 and y==0:
        return -V0
    else:
        return 0.0
U = np.zeros((N)**2).reshape(N,N)
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      U[i,j]= Vpot(x[i],y[j])
V = sparse.diags(U.reshape(N**2),(0))
```

we will get the following error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
because of the meshgrid needed.

Therefore, if my potential is a simple function like $U(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ it is simple as I showed above. But for piecewise potentials I have no idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @michael-seifert. I improved the question for clarification.

Comment: This looks like a computing science problem, not a physics problem. You'll have better luck in the [Computational Science site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, this is purely a python question. The solution seems to be, *use two loops*, but I imagine OP tried that and ran into issues. Better to ask [so] how to use numpy in this manner.

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html will be useful, this enables you to define linear operators directly instead of encoding them as matrices.

Comment: @KyleKanos understood very well the idea. I added a new part explaining better the problem.

Comment: [Numpy's where function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) could be used to fix this problem

Comment: @jpmend again, this is better suited for [so] because it's about how to use numpy. The fact that it is about a physics problem isn't sufficient for it to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the answer for anyone in the future who runs into a similar issue.

Some people have commented that this is more of a computational problem than a physics problem. With this in mind, I searched for the very specific python problem related to the question. I found this very good solution that can be well adapted to the problem posed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037658/plot-a-piecewise-function-in-3d

After properly defining the potential function as mentioned there, one can use

```
U = Vpot(x,y)
V = sparse.diags(U.reshape(N**2),(0))
```

and it is done. You have your potential energy matrix.